# Assign a React.DOMElement class to variable without instantiating it

Tags: reactjs

Let's assume I have React component that looks like this:

```js
const Header = (type, children, ...) => {
    const classes = classNames("header", ...);

    let result;
    if (type === "h1") {
        result = <h1 className={classes} ...>{children}</h1>
    } else if (type === "h2") {
        result = <h2 className={classes} ...>{children}</h2>
    } else if (type === "h3") {
        result = <h3 className={classes} ...>{children}</h3>
    } else if (type === "h4") {
        result = <h4 className={classes} ...>{children}</h4>
    }

    return result;
}
```

As you can see, there's a lot of duplication. I would ideally like to declare the type once, and determine the type of React.DOMElement to render, whether that be , , , or an .

something like this:

```js
const Header = (type, children, ...) => {
    const classes = classNames("header", ...);
    const domElement = type;

    return <domElement className={classes} ...>{children}</domElement>
}
```

Obviously the above doesn't work, so how do you reference the React.DOMElement class and not instantiate it?

Answer (score 1):

the trick is to have the domElement starting by an uppercase, so JSX interprets it (lowercase are for html tags)

```
const TagName = type;
return <TagName className={classes} ...>{children}<TagName/>
```

Answer (score 0):

Instead of using JSX you could return simply:

```
return React.createElement(type, props, children)
```